# Add-ins are disabled while creating a meeting in office 365 group calendar in outlook 2016

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js, office365-apps

I am following this [Article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Schedule-a-meeting-on-a-group-calendar-in-Outlook-0cf1ad68-1034-4306-b367-d75e9818376a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#Outlook=Outlook_2016) to create a new meeting in Office 365 group calendar using Outlook 2016(on Windows 10), But all the add-ins are disabled in outlook 2016 native when using group calendar. The add-ins works fine in web outlook for group calendar and for regular user calendar in outlook 2016 native as well.

Our applications helps to create structured agenda for a meeting but since the add-in is disabled we cant use the app in group calendar using Outlook 2016 native. Here is the screen shot.

[image]

This used to work fine earlier, Do we need to enable some settings so that these add-ins and enabled or is it not supported any more?

Would appreciate if someone can points me to the right direction here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add-ins in shared mailboxes are not supported. The fact that you are able to see them in OWA is a bug, since they only work partially (EWS and REST API do not work).

We plan to make the experience consistent with outlook desktop and the fix is on our backlog. The fix is going to be that, for shared Mailboxes, Add-ins will not show up in OWA as well.

We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](//officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there.

Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

[Outlook Add-ins Engineering Team]

Comment: I've just gone through the last month's worth of answers by your team and made a few edits. There were three main things I noticed. 1) An excessive use of thanks (actually, *any* use of thanks is "frowned" upon on SO ;) ) 2) A slight excess of irrelevant self-promotional material (if you are giving readers some useful info, that is all fine and dandy, but if is just self-congratulatory marketing, well…) 3) An over-verbosity in the template answers (inlined links are better than repeating the same info with an added link).

Comment: These edits are only suggestions, of course. Feel free to change/adapt any as you see fit. If you could share this with all the team members who post here, it should help for a better fit with SO style/expectations. In particular, these edited answers, [one](//stackoverflow.com/a/48086107), [two](//stackoverflow.com/a/48027128), and [three](//stackoverflow.com/a/47759886), could be used as a basis for updated templates.

Comment: The other main issue I noticed was a recent spate of answers that should have been comments instead. (Check your deleted answers to find them.) Could you please make sure that all your team members are aware of the difference between comments and answers. In particular, please make sure that anybody new to Stack Overflow is mentored by someone experienced with the site. Just to recap, answers are for **answering** the asked question. Not for asking for more information/clarification. That's what comments are for. **Stack Overflow is not, and  does not work like, a forum.**

Comment: Thanks for the reply I have created a task in user voice forum. However it is a really useful functionality to have which used to work fine earlier. Some of our customers are already using this functionality using web outlook and would like to have it in native outlook as well. Here is the link https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/32813602-enable-add-ins-while-creating-a-meeting-in-office

Comment: @DeepakSharma were you able to have add-ins on group calendar in the Web?