# Custom add-ins in an office 365 group calendar

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

Can custom add-ins be enabled/used while creating meeting requests in an Office 365 group calendar. The add-ins need to be enabled while creating meetings from Web, Desktop App as well mobile?

I can see that an user voice was raised [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/32813602-enable-add-ins-while-creating-a-meeting-in-office). But it's not clear if the feature was made available or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible today. Since it has been requested by others already, please upvote the [existing request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/32813602-enable-add-ins-while-creating-a-meeting-in-office). Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Is it possible to enable the add-ins in Web while creating meeting requests in Group Calendar?

Comment: No, this feature is not available as of now. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075490/add-ins-are-disabled-while-creating-a-meeting-in-office-365-group-calendar-in-ou for more details.

In the meantime, since it has been requested by others already, please upvote the existing request. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.